# I edited the database but the site's showing old content no longer in it

Tags: database

I needed to find-and-replace text across several nodes in my database, so I exported it via PHPMyAdmin and then ran the find-and-replace on the resultant .sql file. I then dropped all tables in my database and imported the edited .sql file. Now when I inspect my database with PHPMyAdmin I see that the text I removed with the find-and-replace is no longer there; however when I view or edit a node with the text I've replaced I see the replaced text still there. This is despite the fact that if I search for that text in the .sql file I imported (or a fresh .sql export after the import) I don't find it anywhere.

Why is this? How can I fix it, and successfully find-and-replace text in my site with the method above (or some better method, though that's slightly changing the question)?

### Example

If you view source on http://gwwc2.centreforeffectivealtruism.org/node/546 you'll see at the start of the node content:

```
<style type="text/css"> <!--        @page { margin: 2cm }       P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm }         A:link { color: #2198a6; text-decoration: none }    -->     </style>
```

However when I run `SELECT body_value FROM field_revision_body WHERE entity_id=546` (which seems to be the right query as I'm using D7) I don't see this anywhere in what's returned, which instead starts:

```
<p>A perennial criticism
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you refreshed your caches?
Configuration -> Development -> Performance -> Clear all caches

Comment: blush - that fixed it, for some reason I thought I had caching off.